# Swap image with jquery and show zoom image

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, asp-classic

On my site I have an Classic ASP page that shows 4 thumbnail product images that when clicked on swap the main image. This part is working okay. However, on the main image I'm also trying to use the jQZoom script.

The zoom script works for the most part, except that the zoomed image always displays the zoom of the first image, rather than the one selected.

I was wondering if someone might be able to suggest a solution? My code for the page is here;

```
<%

SQL = "Select * from products,subcategories,labels where subcat_id = prod_subcategory and label_id = prod_label and prod_id = " & prodID

set conn = server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
conn.Open(Application("DATABASE"))
set rs = conn.Execute(SQL)

if rs.eof then
    ' product is not valid
    name = "Error - product id " & prodID & " is not available"
else

    image1      = rs.fields("prod_image1")
    image1Desc  = rs.fields("prod_image1Desc")
    icon        = rs.fields("prod_icon")
    subcat      = rs.fields("prod_subcategory")
    image2      = rs.fields("prod_image2")
    image2Desc  = rs.fields("prod_image2Desc")
    image3      = rs.fields("prod_image3")
    image3Desc  = rs.fields("prod_image3Desc")
    image4      = rs.fields("prod_image4")
    image4Desc  = rs.fields("prod_image4Desc")
    zoomimg     = rs.Fields("prod_zoomimg")
    zoomimg2    = rs.Fields("prod_zoomimg2")
    zoomimg3    = rs.Fields("prod_zoomimg3")
    zoomimg4    = rs.Fields("prod_zoomimg4")

    thumb1 = rs.fields("prod_preview1").value
    thumb2 = rs.fields("prod_preview2").value
    thumb3 = rs.fields("prod_preview3").value
    thumb4 = rs.fields("prod_preview4").value

end if
set rs = nothing

conn.Close
set conn = nothing

%>
<!-- #include virtual="/includes/head-product.asp" -->

<body id="detail">
<!-- #include virtual="/includes/header.asp" -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function switchImg(imgName) {
    var ImgX = document.getElementById("mainimg");
    ImgX.src="/images/products/" + imgName;
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var options = {
        zoomWidth: 466,
        zoomHeight: 260,
        xOffset: 34,
        yOffset: 0,
        title: false,
        position: "right" //and MORE OPTIONS
};
    $(".MYCLASS").jqzoom(options);
});

</script>

<!-- #include virtual="/includes/nav.asp" -->

<div id="column-left">
    <div id="main-image">
            <% if oldie = false then %><a href="/images/products/<%=zoomimg%>" class="MYCLASS"  title="MYTITLE"><img src="/images/products/<%=image1%>" title="IMAGE TITLE" name="mainimg" id="mainimg" style="width:425px; height:638px;" ></a><% end if %>

    </div>

</div>
<div id="column-right">
    <div id="altviews">
    <h3 class="altviews">Alternative Views</h3>
    <ul>
        <%
                if oldie = false then
                writeThumb thumb1,image1,zoomimg,image1desc
                writeThumb thumb2,image2,zoomimg2,image2desc
                writeThumb thumb3,image3,zoomimg3,image3desc
                writeThumb thumb4,image4,zoomimg4,image4desc
                end if
        %>
    </ul>
    </div>

</div>

<!-- #include virtual="/includes/footer-test.asp" -->
<%

sub writeThumb(thumbfile, imgfile, zoomfile, thumbdesc)
    response.Write "<li>"
    if thumbfile <> "65/default_preview.jpg" and thumbfile <> "" and not isnull(thumbfile) then 
        if imgFile <> "" and not isnull(imgfile) then rimgfile = replace(imgfile,"/","//") else rimgfile = ""
        if thumbdesc <> "" and not isnull(thumbdesc) then rDescription = replace(thumbdesc,"""","&quot;") else rDescription = ""
        response.write "<img src=""/images/products/"& thumbfile &""" style=""cursor: pointer"" border=""0"" style=""width:65px; height:98px;"" title="""& rDescription &""" onclick=""switchImg('" & rimgfile & "')"" />" & vbcrlf
    else
        response.write "<img src=""/images/products/65/default_preview.jpg"" alt="""" />" & vbCrLF
    end if
    response.write "</li>" & vbCrLF
end sub

%>
```

Comment: I do not see any problem on the site...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `mainimg` is the `id` of the image inside `a`, you only seem to change the thumbnail here, not the main image.

The main image is in `a.href`, you should change it as well and reinstantiate `JQZoom`.

Try this:

```
function switchImg(imgName) {
    $('a.MYCLASS').attr('href', '/images/products/' + imgName);
    $('a.MYCLASS img').attr('src', '/images/products/' + imgName);
    $(".MYCLASS").jqzoom(options);
}
```